# Counting the presence of a key in an object array; key won't be in every element

Tags: powershell, object, arraylist, key

I have an arraylist of log entries containing the following:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$aLog = @()

$aLog.Add([pscustomobject]@{status='200';desc='ok'})
$aLog.Add([pscustomobject]@{status='404';desc='not found';error='not found'})
$aLog.Add([pscustomobject]@{status='201';desc='created'})
$aLog.Add([pscustomobject]@{status='404';desc='unauthorized';error='unauthorized'})
```

I want to list the number of entries that have don't have an error:

```
"Success: xx of $(@($aLog).count)"
```

How do I count the rows containing a key of `error` so I can subtract it from the total?

Comment: `$aLog | ? {$null -eq $_.error}`

Comment: `$aLog.Where{ $_.Error }.Count` also faster than `| ?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"error" -in $_.PSobject.Properties.Name` along with `Where-Object` to filter out objects that has the `error` property, and then use `Count` property to get the total count.

```
$failureCount = ($aLog | Where-Object { "error" -in $_.PSobject.Properties.Name }).Count
```